# How to make a graph tick every second in kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Am new to Kibana and elastic search. I have managed to get everything working, except for the graph ticking every second.

I am continuously feeding data into the ELK stack (local test machine), and its getting loaded into the index in elastic search , and i am also able to see the graph or bar chart getting updated (if i refresh the page in kibana 4), but i am not able to make it tick every second or so  in the same screen without refreshing the page  :(  , am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana provide the Auto-refresh option in the top-right corner. It will load the data for every five seconds to one day without refreshing the whole page.

[image]

[www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html#dash-autorefresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html#dash-autorefresh)